# React Select Unexpected token, expected "..." (56:53)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a useState where I am pulling up my role from MongoDB:

```
const [role, setRole] = useState('')
```

On Edit screen I am trying to just select the ones that is equal to the current selected role so what I did is that I created a conditional statement:

```
<div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="phone">User Role</label>
                  <select class="form-control" onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}>
                     <option value="administrator" { role === 'administrator' ? selected : ''} >Administrator</option>
                     <option value="editor" { role === 'editor' ? selected : ''}>Editor</option>
                     <option value="subscriber"{ role === 'reviewer' ? selected : ''}>Subscriber</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
```

But this returns an error:

```
./src/screens/UserEditScreen.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Grole\Desktop\Creen\Play\react\src\screens\UserEditScreen.js: Unexpected token, expected "..." (56:53)

  54 |                 <label for="phone">User Role</label>
  55 |                   <select class="form-control" onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}>
> 56 |                      <option value="administrator" { role === 'administrator' ? selected : ''} >Administrator</option>
     |                                                      ^
  57 |                      <option value="editor" { role === 'editor' ? selected : ''}>Editor</option>
  58 |                      <option value="subscriber"{ role === 'subscriber' ? selected : ''}>Subscriber</option>
  59 |                   </select>
```

Not sure why its asking to for the triple dots to fix this, here's my complete code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import  Message from '../components/Message'
import  Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { getUserDetails } from '../actions/userActions'

const UserEditScreen = ({ match, history }) => {

    const userId = match.params.id

    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
    const [role, setRole] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails)
    const { loading, error, user } = userDetails 

     useEffect(() => {
       if(!user.name || user._id !== userId){
          dispatch(getUserDetails(userId))
       } else {
           setName(user.name)
           setName(user.email)
           setName(user.phone)
           setName(user.role)
       }
     }, [dispatch, userId, user])

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return ( 
        <>
            <h1>Edit User</h1>
    { loading ? <Loader /> : error ? <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message> : (
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}> 
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value={name} className="form-control" id="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" name="email"  value={email} className="form-control" id="email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{9}"  value={phone} className="form-control" id="phone" onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}  />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group"> 
                <label for="phone">User Role</label>
                  <select class="form-control" onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}>
                     <option value="administrator" { role === 'administrator' ? selected : ''} >Administrator</option>
                     <option value="editor" { role === 'editor' ? selected : ''}>Editor</option>
                     <option value="subscriber"{ role === 'subscriber' ? selected : ''}>Subscriber</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            </form>
            
    )}

        </>
    )
}

export default UserEditScreen
```

How do I fix this and select the current role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<option value="administrator" selected={role === 'administrator'} >Administrator</option>
<option value="editor" selected={role === 'editor'}>Editor</option>
<option value="subscriber" selected={role === 'reviewer'}>Subscriber</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the condition in classname

```js
<div className="form-group"> 
<label for="phone">User Role</label>
  <select class="form-control" onChange={(e) => setRole(e.target.value)}>
     <option value="administrator" classname={`${role === 'administrator' && 'selected'}`}>Administrator</option>
     <option value="editor" classname={`${role === 'editor' && 'selected'}`}>Editor</option>
     <option value="subscriber" classname={`${role === 'reviewer' && 'selected'}`}>Subscriber</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying this??

```js
<option value="administrator" selected={role === 'administrator'}>Administrator</option>
<option value="editor" selected={role === 'editor'}>Editor</option>
<option value="subscriber" selected={role === 'subscriber'}>Subscriber</option>
```

And, by the way, below is what you intended??

It looks something weird for me that using `setName` to each value several times.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if(!user.name || user._id !== userId){
      dispatch(getUserDetails(userId))
   } else {
       setName(user.name)
       setName(user.email)
       setName(user.phone)
       setName(user.role)
   }
 }, [dispatch, userId, user])
```